# Power Bi gives error in m language - token comma expected

Tags: powerbi

When using this code:

```
(LatStart as text, LonStart as text, LatDest as text, LonDest as text)=>
let
Source = Xml.Tables(Web.Contents("https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/",
[
RelativePath="DistanceMatrix",
Query =[
origins="" & LatStart & "," & LonStart &"",
destinations="" & LatDest & "," & LonDest & "",
travelMode="driving",
distanceUnit="km",
timeUnit="minute",
o="xml",
key=gu9tL5NeUo6CsNKZWj00~o05Bp1GQ76ISmSrxiptgBQ~AoBvsa-SMlEHUcZuCl6tIVBRbDZDq0QDBuZBdpNfTUao5AzK3ua-pwaBl1AcwiPu
]
]
)
),
#"Geänderter Typ" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Quelle,{{"Copyright", type text}, {"BrandLogoUri", type text}, {"StatusCode", Int64.Type}, {"StatusDescription", type text}, {"AuthenticationResultCode", type text}, {"TraceId", type text}}),
ResourceSets = #"Geänderter Typ"{0}[ResourceSets],
ResourceSet = ResourceSets{0}[ResourceSet],
#"Geänderter Typ1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(ResourceSet,{{"EstimatedTotal", Int64.Type}}),
Resources = #"Geänderter Typ1"{0}[Resources],
Resource = Resources{0}[Resource],
Results = Resource{0}[Results],
Distance = Results{0}[Distance],
#"Geänderter Typ2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Distance,{{"OriginIndex", Int64.Type}, {"DestinationIndex", Int64.Type}, {"TravelDistance", Int64.Type}, {"TravelDuration", Int64.Type}, {"TotalWalkDuration", Int64.Type}})
in
#"Geänderter Typ2"
```

Power Bi gives me an error **token comma expected** inside my `key=` value at the first `~`

```
key=gu9tL5NeUo6CsNKZWj00~o05Bp1GQ76ISmSrxiptgBQ~AoBvsa-SMlEHUcZuCl6tIVBRbDZDq0QDBuZBdpNfTUao5AzK3ua-pwaBl1AcwiPu
```

Comment: I hope you didn't disclose anything private with that key here

Comment: thanks for your note but (of course) i changed the key :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your key in quotes like this:

```
"key=gu9tL5NeUo6CsNKZWj00~o05Bp1GQ76ISmSrxiptgBQ~AoBvsa-SMlEHUcZuCl6tIVBRbDZDq0QDBuZBdpNfTUao5AzK3ua-pwaBl1AcwiPu"
```